# why can't i import my custom component in react native

Tags: react-native, import, components, custom-component

i created these components and i was trying to import them in App.js but it shows me an error message, i tried to change the export default class multiple times , i chaged the order of import lines to figure out if there'e an error in the importing of one of the components, but nothing changed and still shows me the same error message, how can i fix it

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {ActivityIndicator,Keyboard,KeyboardAvoidingView,StyleSheet} from "react-native";

import { theme } from './constants';
import  Block from './app/components' ; 
import  Button from './app/components' ; 
import  Text from './app/components' ; 
import  Input from './app/components' ; 

const VALID_EMAIL = "contact@react-ui-kit.com";
const VALID_PASSWORD = "subscribe";

export default class Login extends Component {
  state = {
    email: VALID_EMAIL,
    password: VALID_PASSWORD,
    errors: [],
    loading: false
  };

  handleLogin() {
    const { navigation } = this.props;
    const { email, password } = this.state;
    const errors = [];

    Keyboard.dismiss();
    this.setState({ loading: true });

    // check with backend API or with some static data
    if (email !== VALID_EMAIL) {
      errors.push("email");
    }
    if (password !== VALID_PASSWORD) {
      errors.push("password");
    }

    this.setState({ errors, loading: false });

    if (!errors.length) {
      navigation.navigate("Browse");
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { navigation } = this.props;
    const { loading, errors } = this.state;
    const hasErrors = key => (errors.includes(key) ? styles.hasErrors : null);

    return (
      <KeyboardAvoidingView style={styles.login} behavior="padding">
        <Block padding={[0, theme.sizes.base * 2]}>
          <Text h1 bold>
            Login
          </Text>
          <Block middle>
            <Input
              label="Email"
              error={hasErrors("email")}
              style={[styles.input, hasErrors("email")]}
              defaultValue={this.state.email}
              onChangeText={text => this.setState({ email: text })}
            />
            <Input
              secure
              label="Password"
              error={hasErrors("password")}
              style={[styles.input, hasErrors("password")]}
              defaultValue={this.state.password}
              onChangeText={text => this.setState({ password: text })}
            />
            <Button gradient onPress={() => this.handleLogin()}>
              {loading ? (
                <ActivityIndicator size="small" color="white" />
              ) : (
                <Text bold white center>
                  Login
                </Text>
              )}
            </Button>

            <Button onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Forgot")}>
              <Text
                gray
                caption
                center
                style={{ textDecorationLine: "underline" }}
              >
                Forgot your password?
              </Text>
            </Button>
          </Block>
        </Block>
      </KeyboardAvoidingView>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  login: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center"
  },
  input: {
    borderRadius: 0,
    borderWidth: 0,
    borderBottomColor: theme.colors.gray2,
    borderBottomWidth: StyleSheet.hairlineWidth
  },
  hasErrors: {
    borderBottomColor: theme.colors.accent
  }
});
```

**Block.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { StyleSheet, View, Animated } from "react-native";

import { theme } from "./constants";

export default class Block extends Component {
  handleMargins() {
    const { margin } = this.props;
    if (typeof margin === "number") {
      return {
        marginTop: margin,
        marginRight: margin,
        marginBottom: margin,
        marginLeft: margin
      };
    }

    if (typeof margin === "object") {
      const marginSize = Object.keys(margin).length;
      switch (marginSize) {
        case 1:
          return {
            marginTop: margin[0],
            marginRight: margin[0],
            marginBottom: margin[0],
            marginLeft: margin[0]
          };
        case 2:
          return {
            marginTop: margin[0],
            marginRight: margin[1],
            marginBottom: margin[0],
            marginLeft: margin[1]
          };
        case 3:
          return {
            marginTop: margin[0],
            marginRight: margin[1],
            marginBottom: margin[2],
            marginLeft: margin[1]
          };
        default:
          return {
            marginTop: margin[0],
            marginRight: margin[1],
            marginBottom: margin[2],
            marginLeft: margin[3]
          };
      }
    }
  }

  handlePaddings() {
    const { padding } = this.props;
    if (typeof padding === "number") {
      return {
        paddingTop: padding,
        paddingRight: padding,
        paddingBottom: padding,
        paddingLeft: padding
      };
    }

    if (typeof padding === "object") {
      const paddingSize = Object.keys(padding).length;
      switch (paddingSize) {
        case 1:
          return {
            paddingTop: padding[0],
            paddingRight: padding[0],
            paddingBottom: padding[0],
            paddingLeft: padding[0]
          };
        case 2:
          return {
            paddingTop: padding[0],
            paddingRight: padding[1],
            paddingBottom: padding[0],
            paddingLeft: padding[1]
          };
        case 3:
          return {
            paddingTop: padding[0],
            paddingRight: padding[1],
            paddingBottom: padding[2],
            paddingLeft: padding[1]
          };
        default:
          return {
            paddingTop: padding[0],
            paddingRight: padding[1],
            paddingBottom: padding[2],
            paddingLeft: padding[3]
          };
      }
    }
  }

  render() {
    const {
      flex,
      row,
      column,
      center,
      middle,
      left,
      right,
      top,
      bottom,
      card,
      shadow,
      color,
      space,
      padding,
      margin,
      animated,
      wrap,
      style,
      children,
      ...props
    } = this.props;

    const blockStyles = [
      styles.block,
      flex && { flex },
      flex === false && { flex: 0 }, // reset / disable flex
      row && styles.row,
      column && styles.column,
      center && styles.center,
      middle && styles.middle,
      left && styles.left,
      right && styles.right,
      top && styles.top,
      bottom && styles.bottom,
      margin && { ...this.handleMargins() },
      padding && { ...this.handlePaddings() },
      card && styles.card,
      shadow && styles.shadow,
      space && { justifyContent: `space-${space}` },
      wrap && { flexWrap: "wrap" },
      color && styles[color], // predefined styles colors for backgroundColor
      color && !styles[color] && { backgroundColor: color }, // custom backgroundColor
      style // rewrite predefined styles
    ];

    if (animated) {
      return (
        <Animated.View style={blockStyles} {...props}>
          {children}
        </Animated.View>
      );
    }

    return (
      <View style={blockStyles} {...props}>
        {children}
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  block: {
    flex: 1
  },
  row: {
    flexDirection: "row"
  },
  column: {
    flexDirection: "column"
  },
  card: {
    borderRadius: theme.sizes.radius
  },
  center: {
    alignItems: "center"
  },
  middle: {
    justifyContent: "center"
  },
  left: {
    justifyContent: "flex-start"
  },
  right: {
    justifyContent: "flex-end"
  },
  top: {
    justifyContent: "flex-start"
  },
  bottom: {
    justifyContent: "flex-end"
  },
  shadow: {
    shadowColor: theme.colors.black,
    shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 2 },
    shadowOpacity: 0.1,
    shadowRadius: 13,
    elevation: 2
  },
  accent: { backgroundColor: theme.colors.accent },
  primary: { backgroundColor: theme.colors.primary },
  secondary: { backgroundColor: theme.colors.secondary },
  tertiary: { backgroundColor: theme.colors.tertiary },
  black: { backgroundColor: theme.colors.black },
  white: { backgroundColor: theme.colors.white },
  gray: { backgroundColor: theme.colors.gray },
  gray2: { backgroundColor: theme.colors.gray2 }
});
```

**Text.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Text, StyleSheet } from "react-native";

import { theme } from "./constants";

export default class Typography extends Component {
  render() {
    const {
      h1,
      h2,
      h3,
      title,
      body,
      caption,
      small,
      size,
      transform,
      align,
      // styling
      regular,
      bold,
      semibold,
      medium,
      weight,
      light,
      center,
      right,
      spacing, // letter-spacing
      height, // line-height
      // colors
      color,
      accent,
      primary,
      secondary,
      tertiary,
      black,
      white,
      gray,
      gray2,
      style,
      children,
      ...props
    } = this.props;

    const textStyles = [
      styles.text,
      h1 && styles.h1,
      h2 && styles.h2,
      h3 && styles.h3,
      title && styles.title,
      body && styles.body,
      caption && styles.caption,
      small && styles.small,
      size && { fontSize: size },
      transform && { textTransform: transform },
      align && { textAlign: align },
      height && { lineHeight: height },
      spacing && { letterSpacing: spacing },
      weight && { fontWeight: weight },
      regular && styles.regular,
      bold && styles.bold,
      semibold && styles.semibold,
      medium && styles.medium,
      light && styles.light,
      center && styles.center,
      right && styles.right,
      color && styles[color],
      color && !styles[color] && { color },
      // color shortcuts
      accent && styles.accent,
      primary && styles.primary,
      secondary && styles.secondary,
      tertiary && styles.tertiary,
      black && styles.black,
      white && styles.white,
      gray && styles.gray,
      gray2 && styles.gray2,
      style // rewrite predefined styles
    ];

    return (
      <Text style={textStyles} {...props}>
        {children}
      </Text>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  // default style
  text: {
    fontSize: theme.sizes.font,
    color: theme.colors.black
  },
  // variations
  regular: {
    fontWeight: "normal"
  },
  bold: {
    fontWeight: "bold"
  },
  semibold: {
    fontWeight: "500"
  },
  medium: {
    fontWeight: "500"
  },
  light: {
    fontWeight: "200"
  },
  // position
  center: { textAlign: "center" },
  right: { textAlign: "right" },
  // colors
  accent: { color: theme.colors.accent },
  primary: { color: theme.colors.primary },
  secondary: { color: theme.colors.secondary },
  tertiary: { color: theme.colors.tertiary },
  black: { color: theme.colors.black },
  white: { color: theme.colors.white },
  gray: { color: theme.colors.gray },
  gray2: { color: theme.colors.gray2 },
  // fonts
  h1: theme.fonts.h1,
  h2: theme.fonts.h2,
  h3: theme.fonts.h3,
  title: theme.fonts.title,
  body: theme.fonts.body,
  caption: theme.fonts.caption,
  small: theme.fonts.small
});
```

**Button.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";
import { LinearGradient } from "react-native-linear-gradient";
import { theme } from "./constants";

class Button extends Component {
  render() {
    const {
      style,
      opacity,
      gradient,
      color,
      startColor,
      endColor,
      end,
      start,
      locations,
      shadow,
      children,
      ...props
    } = this.props;

    const buttonStyles = [
      styles.button,
      shadow && styles.shadow,
      color && styles[color], // predefined styles colors for backgroundColor
      color && !styles[color] && { backgroundColor: color }, // custom backgroundColor
      style
    ];

    if (gradient) {
      return (
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={buttonStyles}
          activeOpacity={opacity}
          {...props}
        >
          <LinearGradient
            start={start}
            end={end}
            locations={locations}
            style={buttonStyles}
            colors={[startColor, endColor]}
          >
            {children}
          </LinearGradient> */
        </TouchableOpacity>
      );
    }

    return (
      <TouchableOpacity
        style={buttonStyles}
        activeOpacity={opacity || 0.8}
        {...props}
      >
        {children}
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  }
}

Button.defaultProps = {
  startColor: theme.colors.primary,
  endColor: theme.colors.secondary,
  start: { x: 0, y: 0 },
  end: { x: 1, y: 1 },
  locations: [0.1, 0.9],
  opacity: 0.8,
  color: theme.colors.white
};

export default Button;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  button: {
    borderRadius: theme.sizes.radius,
    height: theme.sizes.base * 3,
    justifyContent: "center",
    marginVertical: theme.sizes.padding / 3
  },
  shadow: {
    shadowColor: theme.colors.black,
    shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 2 },
    shadowOpacity: 0.1,
    shadowRadius: 10
  },
  accent: { backgroundColor: theme.colors.accent },
  primary: { backgroundColor: theme.colors.primary },
  secondary: { backgroundColor: theme.colors.secondary },
  tertiary: { backgroundColor: theme.colors.tertiary },
  black: { backgroundColor: theme.colors.black },
  white: { backgroundColor: theme.colors.white },
  gray: { backgroundColor: theme.colors.gray },
  gray2: { backgroundColor: theme.colors.gray2 },
  gray3: { backgroundColor: theme.colors.gray3 },
  gray4: { backgroundColor: theme.colors.gray4 }
});
```

**Input.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { StyleSheet, View, Animated } from "react-native";

import { theme } from "./constants";

export default class Block extends Component {
  handleMargins() {
    const { margin } = this.props;
    if (typeof margin === "number") {
      return {
        marginTop: margin,
        marginRight: margin,
        marginBottom: margin,
        marginLeft: margin
      };
    }

    if (typeof margin === "object") {
      const marginSize = Object.keys(margin).length;
      switch (marginSize) {
        case 1:
          return {
            marginTop: margin[0],
            marginRight: margin[0],
            marginBottom: margin[0],
            marginLeft: margin[0]
          };
        case 2:
          return {
            marginTop: margin[0],
            marginRight: margin[1],
            marginBottom: margin[0],
            marginLeft: margin[1]
          };
        case 3:
          return {
            marginTop: margin[0],
            marginRight: margin[1],
            marginBottom: margin[2],
            marginLeft: margin[1]
          };
        default:
          return {
            marginTop: margin[0],
            marginRight: margin[1],
            marginBottom: margin[2],
            marginLeft: margin[3]
          };
      }
    }
  }

  handlePaddings() {
    const { padding } = this.props;
    if (typeof padding === "number") {
      return {
        paddingTop: padding,
        paddingRight: padding,
        paddingBottom: padding,
        paddingLeft: padding
      };
    }

    if (typeof padding === "object") {
      const paddingSize = Object.keys(padding).length;
      switch (paddingSize) {
        case 1:
          return {
            paddingTop: padding[0],
            paddingRight: padding[0],
            paddingBottom: padding[0],
            paddingLeft: padding[0]
          };
        case 2:
          return {
            paddingTop: padding[0],
            paddingRight: padding[1],
            paddingBottom: padding[0],
            paddingLeft: padding[1]
          };
        case 3:
          return {
            paddingTop: padding[0],
            paddingRight: padding[1],
            paddingBottom: padding[2],
            paddingLeft: padding[1]
          };
        default:
          return {
            paddingTop: padding[0],
            paddingRight: padding[1],
            paddingBottom: padding[2],
            paddingLeft: padding[3]
          };
      }
    }
  }

  render() {
    const {
      flex,
      row,
      column,
      center,
      middle,
      left,
      right,
      top,
      bottom,
      card,
      shadow,
      color,
      space,
      padding,
      margin,
      animated,
      wrap,
      style,
      children,
      ...props
    } = this.props;

    const blockStyles = [
      styles.block,
      flex && { flex },
      flex === false && { flex: 0 }, // reset / disable flex
      row && styles.row,
      column && styles.column,
      center && styles.center,
      middle && styles.middle,
      left && styles.left,
      right && styles.right,
      top && styles.top,
      bottom && styles.bottom,
      margin && { ...this.handleMargins() },
      padding && { ...this.handlePaddings() },
      card && styles.card,
      shadow && styles.shadow,
      space && { justifyContent: `space-${space}` },
      wrap && { flexWrap: "wrap" },
      color && styles[color], // predefined styles colors for backgroundColor
      color && !styles[color] && { backgroundColor: color }, // custom backgroundColor
      style // rewrite predefined styles
    ];

    if (animated) {
      return (
        <Animated.View style={blockStyles} {...props}>
          {children}
        </Animated.View>
      );
    }

    return (
      <View style={blockStyles} {...props}>
        {children}
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  block: {
    flex: 1
  },
  row: {
    flexDirection: "row"
  },
  column: {
    flexDirection: "column"
  },
  card: {
    borderRadius: theme.sizes.radius
  },
  center: {
    alignItems: "center"
  },
  middle: {
    justifyContent: "center"
  },
  left: {
    justifyContent: "flex-start"
  },
  right: {
    justifyContent: "flex-end"
  },
  top: {
    justifyContent: "flex-start"
  },
  bottom: {
    justifyContent: "flex-end"
  },
  shadow: {
    shadowColor: theme.colors.black,
    shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 2 },
    shadowOpacity: 0.1,
    shadowRadius: 13,
    elevation: 2
  },
  accent: { backgroundColor: theme.colors.accent },
  primary: { backgroundColor: theme.colors.primary },
  secondary: { backgroundColor: theme.colors.secondary },
  tertiary: { backgroundColor: theme.colors.tertiary },
  black: { backgroundColor: theme.colors.black },
  white: { backgroundColor: theme.colors.white },
  gray: { backgroundColor: theme.colors.gray },
  gray2: { backgroundColor: theme.colors.gray2 }
});
```

the error

```
Error: Unable to resolve module ./components from C:\Users\DELL\wan_way_service_app\App.js:

None of these files exist:
  * components(.native|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.json|.native.json|.json|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)
  * components\index(.native|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.json|.native.json|.json|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)
  3 |
  4 | import { theme } from './constants';
> 5 | import  Button from './components' ;
    |                      ^
  6 | import  Block from './components' ;
  7 | import  Text from './components' ;
  8 | import  Input from './components' ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you exporting your component correctly?

OPTION 1 - if you are exporting one component per file, you can use the "export default" Example:

```js
export default Class ClassName = () => {
  return <View />;
}
```

and to import use

```js
import ClassName from './app/components'
```

OPTION 2 - If there are several components, you have to export as a constant in this way

```js
export Class ClassName = () => {
  return <View />;
}
export Class OtherClassName = () => {
  return <View />;
}
```

and to import use

```js
import {ClassName, OtherClassName} from './app/components'
```

it depends on the way your folder structure is being created, by default and for a cleaner code the ideal is like this:

```
myAwesomeProject
  src
   | components
   | |  ComponentOne
   | |  | index.js
   | |  ComponentTwo
   | |  | index.js
```

and that way you can use the default export

Comment: export default class Block extends Component {
render ()
{ <component> }
}

Comment: but in your Button class you are not exporting this way See the code you sent from Button.js. If you can add the full code of your components it would help

Comment: i read an answer about export default class and export class so i tried both of them and they didn't work

Comment: Edit your question, and add the complete code of your component so we can have more details

Comment: check it now bro

Comment: I removed line 74 from the export default button and added it before the name of your class on line 6, and the import worked normally. Check the edit

Comment: I believe this is your problem, see the edit now